# Reason to use useMemo in react js

Tags: reactjs

In my react js application i have a reduce function that is responsible to loop trough an array of 4 strings and to return a string with all these items. Is there a reason to wrap the function with useMemo hook or it is redundant in this situation?

Comment: Disagree with the answer. 1) You shouldn't spend time pre-optimizing your code if there is no performance concerns. 2) An array of 4 strings is not computationally expensive, and so there is no reason to memoize the result.

Answer (score -1):

`useMemo` caches the result of the given function so It's not recalculated on every re-render.

Whether to memoize depends on how often the function's dependencies change. Still it's unlikely that you need to recalculate the value on every render, so generally its a good idea to wrap it with useMemo